# How to stop the local parent shell when error occurred in remote shell script?

Tags: shell-script

I'm trying to run shell script on remote server with my local shell script.
And I have to stop my local shell script when error occurred in remote shell script.

I'm running the remote shell script via ssh like this.

```bsh
##parent shell script##
#!/bin/bash -ex
scp remote_shell.sh ${host}:${path}
ssh ${host} '${path}/remote_shell.sh ; rm ${path}/remote_shell.sh'
..do something
```

```bsh
##remote_shell.sh##
#!/bin/bash -ex
..do something
..error occurred
exit 1
```

The problem is, when remote_shell.sh exit with 1, but parent shell wouldn't stop.

I tried this script on local(without ssh), and parent stops as I expected.
Is this problem related to the third line ';' operator?
(I have to remove remote_shell.sh file regardless of failure.)

Of course I can achieve this with some If Else code, but I want to make it simple..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
ssh ${host} '${path}/remote_shell.sh'
```

Or

```
ssh ${host} '${path}/remote_shell.sh ; R=$?; rm ${path}/remote_shell.sh; exit $R'
```

Or some other way of preserving the exit code

Comment: Thanks! I works for my case!